# Control horizontal and vertical space in grid.arrange with sliders in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I need to create a shiny app in which the user decides how many charts to display and in how many columns via sliders.
To merge the graphs I used the function `grid.arrange` but it is not mandatory, the important thing is to have ggplot objects. And I need `coord_fixed()`.
This is a small executable example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggforce) 
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
 
    navbarPage("MotorBrain", 
               
      tabPanel("Configurazione",
               sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel( 
                      sliderInput("input1", "N. utenti",
                                    min = 1, max = 133,
                                    value = 3),
                       sliderInput("nCol1", "Ncols",
                                    min = 1, max = 32,
                                    value = 1),
                       actionButton("goButton1", "Visualizza")),
                       fluidRow()))),
      tabPanel("Visualizzazione", 
            fluidRow(
                   uiOutput("outputTest1"))
               
 ))




server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
 input1<-eventReactive(input$goButton1,{
        input$input1
    })
output$outputTest1 <- renderUI({ 
pl <- vector("list", length =  input1())
                        
for(t in 1: input1()) {

      p<-ggplot() +
         geom_point(x=runif(10000,0, 1),y=runif(500,0, 1))+
         coord_fixed()
                             
 pl[[t]] <-p
                         
 }
                        
output$plot_test1<- renderPlot({
                    
 grid.arrange(grobs=pl,ncol=input$nCol1,top="")
                                
  })
                        
plotOutput(outputId = "plot_test1")
                        
 })                 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I need to add two more sliders with which the user can decide how much horizontal and vertical white space to put between the various graphs in the grid.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gridExtra` added uncontrollable space between columns, so one solution is to use `patchwork` instead, where no extra space is added. Then we can use `margin` tricks to add space:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggforce) 
library(patchwork)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    navbarPage("MotorBrain", 
               
               tabPanel("Configurazione",
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel( 
                                sliderInput("input1", "N. utenti",
                                            min = 1, max = 133,
                                            value = 3),
                                sliderInput("nCol1", "Ncols",
                                            min = 1, max = 32,
                                            value = 1),
                                sliderInput("h_space", "top bottom space (pt)",
                                            min = 1, max = 100,
                                            value = 1),
                                sliderInput("v_space", " left right space (pt)",
                                            min = 1, max = 100,
                                            value = 1),
                                actionButton("goButton1", "Visualizza")),
                            fluidRow()))),
    tabPanel("Visualizzazione", 
             fluidRow(
                 uiOutput("outputTest1"))
             
    ))




server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    input1<-eventReactive(input$goButton1,{
        input$input1
    })
    output$outputTest1 <- renderUI({ 
        pl <- vector("list", length =  input1())
        for(t in 1: input1()) {
            p<-ggplot() +
                geom_point(x=runif(10000,0, 1),y=runif(500,0, 1))+
                coord_fixed() +
                # the space is added to both sides, so we need to reduce by half
                theme(plot.margin = unit(c(
                    input$h_space/2,
                    input$v_space/2,
                    input$h_space/2,
                    input$v_space/2
                ), "pt"))
            
            pl[[t]] <-p
            
        }
        
        output$plot_test1<- renderPlot({
            Reduce(`+`, pl) +
                plot_layout(ncol = input$nCol1)
        })
        
        plotOutput(outputId = "plot_test1")
        
    })                 
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```